# How to Write GRUB stage1.S in NASM?

Tags: gcc, assembly, operating-system, nasm, bootloader

I am trying to write a multi stage boot loader using NASM and gcc.
For this purpose I am referring grub boot loader source.

I have written a stage1 loader, but stuck at over writing partition
tables of MBR.

In grub stage1.S, they are using code like this to skip partition tables:

```
. = _start + STAGE1_PARTEND
.word   STAGE1_SIGNATURE
```

How can I do that in NASM?.

using times it will over write the partition tables.

So please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Assigning a value to . is treated the same as a .org directive

(see [this page](http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/gnuasm.html#SEC49)).

Thus, the code you pasted is changing the [current origin](http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/gnuasm.html#SEC112) to `_start + STAGE1_PARTEND` and placing a word with the value `STAGE1_SIGNATURE` there.

So in NASM code you should be able to do something like:

```
fill: times _start+STAGE1_PARTEND-$ db 0
dw    STAGE1_SIGNATURE
                     ; .word is 16 bits on x86 (regardless of .code16 / .code64)
```

Also see [this example](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdo12.html#section-12.1.3) in the NASM manual showing how to pad a BIOS boot sector this way, as a replacement for MASM-style `org` or GAS-style `. = new_position` actually seeking and filling with padding in a flat binary output file.

Comment: But using times _start+STAGE1_PARTEND-$ db 0
will over write my partition table entries in MBR.
That is what I wanted to avoid.

Ok, then as u said '.' is similar to 'org' in nasm.
so can I use it as [org _start+STAGE1_PARTEND]

Comment: @Dnyanesh: `.org` in GAS will also effectively fill the space between the current location and the target location with zeroes. The `org` directive in NASM does not behave the same way as in GAS and should not be used as a direct replacement. In fact, the NASM manual contains a specific example of creating an MBR where they say that `times` is the correct directive to use: http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdo12.html#section-12.1.3

Comment: So then how can I avoid over writing partition tables in MBR?
one thing I can do is write stage1 to MBR upto 446 bytes, then how can I write 0xAA55 at the end of MBR?

Comment: `times` will not overwrite existing data in the section. The idea is to pad up til the target location (`_start+STAGE1_PARTEND`) in an easy way. If you're already at the target location then no padding is necessary. Otherwise it will fill the remaining space with zeroes, just like the GAS code you pasted would.

Answer (score 0):

```
times STAGE1_PARTEND-($-_start) db 0
dw STAGE1_SIGNATURE
```

Answer (score -1):

Right, Nasm will accept only one "org" directive. The Nasm equivalent of "." is "$", but I don't think that'll help you either. I don't have the GRUB code on hand, or I'd look. Where does the partition table "come from"? If it's read from disk, there may be a signature already in place(?). Perhaps you can simply "stop" the Nasm code before overwriting the partition table and leave the existing sig in place? Nasm will do almost "anything you want", but this may be an exception. It won't "move" (skip) and assemble more at a new place as (G)as is apparently doing here - at least not readily. I may need to download the GRUB code to figure out a workaround. Possibly something like...

```
; stage1 code
; possible padding here?
%incbin "partition_table.bin"
dw (SIG) ; if not part of the .bin code?
```

... or something.